# Check if cell contains keywords from another cell - Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm putting together a social media content template for my business in Google Sheets. It will mostly have simple formulas and conditional formatting to check for length and what not.

now, what I'm struggling with is the following:

I have a cell, let's call it A2 - A user will enter their content in here. in C2 I have a list of keywords, with a comma as a delimiter which are "keywords" for the user to use for SEO purposes.

I was hoping someone could tell me some wizardry to do the following.

To check Cell A2 for *any*, words in c2 and output how many words are used with a count function.

so for the following

```
Text                             Keywords       Count
Stackoverflow is a lovely place. Place, lovely. 2
```

I have thought about using RegexMatches nested within an IF statement, possibly with a COUNT.

I've come up with this so far, but I don't think I'm going about this the right way.

```
=if(REGEXMATCH(A2, C2), "", "fail")
```

I've also toyed with Find, but couldn't figure it out.

```
=if(A2=(find(C2)),"Found", "fail")
```

As I'm dealing with PhD/Subject specialists in an education NGO trying to get them to adhere to SEO is quite difficult without a lot of manual intervention, so this would be a big help.

Demo Sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15_7eJwCtQArNHihShQdZcpoX91ROvJ5mbnkRaZRI5x4/edit?usp=sharing

what would be more amazing would be to return custom strings inplace of the count function but that's probably stretching it.

Hopefully this is clear, if not please let me know i'll rephrase it.

Cheers,
DN.

Comment: Keyword: use `|` instead of `, `.Don't use a `.` at the end.

Comment: Cheers, but what formula would you use to count the string matches ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming keywords are separated by `|` instead of `,`,

```
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"(?i)\b"&C2&"\b","㊙"),"[^㊙]",))
```

- Inner REPLACE  to change all keywords to `㊙`
- Outer REGEX to change everything else other than `㊙` to
- Return the LENgth of remaining string

Comment: Thanks! This method returns the count of each keyword which appears in my string, I'm still quite shitty with regex, but I don't understand the outer and inner replace with the regex..? why have you used an oriental character? Am i missing something basic here?

Comment: Thanks buddy this makes total sense now (after going through a few YT tutorials on regex) thanks for two things - forcing me to understand regex and providing your very elegant solution!