# Count occurrences of a specific word in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting, google-sheets-query

I have some cells with text. I need to count the occurrences of a specific word (not a list) from those cells.

Example sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WECDbepLtZNwNfUmjxfKlCbLJgjyUBB72yvWDMzDBB0/edit?usp=sharing

So far I found one way to count it in English by using SUBSTITUTE to replace all these words with "":

```
=(LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(B1),UPPER(A5),"")))/LEN(A5)
```

However, I don't know why but it doesn't work in German.

**Edited:**
I don't want to count "Hero" in "Heroes". However, I'd like to count "afk" in "AFK-Spiel" (German for example). Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if cell contains keywords from another cell - Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620202/check-if-cell-contains-keywords-from-another-cell-google-sheets)

Comment: No it doesn't please take a look at my demo sheet.

Answer (score 5):

### If you want to count occurences of "Hero" word

```
=COUNTIF(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", B1:B3), " -."&CHAR(10)), "Hero")
```

*Where:*

- `B1:B3`: cells with text
- `"Hero"`: the word to count

**Explaination**

1. `JOIN(" ", B1:B3)`: Concatenation of all cells with text
2. `SPLIT(..., " -."&CHAR(10))`: Create an array with each words
3. `COUNTIF(..., "Hero")`: Count each array item equals to  "Hero"

**Example**

if input text is:

```
Hero Hero-666 heroes heroic
```

➔ then formula will return **2**.

---

### If you want to count occurences of "Hero" string

### (Even nested in an other word, i.e: "Heroes")

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(UPPER(JOIN(" ",B1:B3)), "HERO", false, false))-1
```

*Where:*

- `B1:B3`: cells with text
- `"HERO"`: the string to count

**Explaination**

1. `JOIN(" ", B1:B3)`: Concatenation of all cells with text
2. `UPPER(...)`: Convert text in upper case
3. `SPLIT(..., "HERO")`: Split on each occurences of the string
4. `COUNTA(...)-1`: Count how many splits have been done

**Example**

if input text is:

```
Hero Hero-666 heroes heroic
```

➔ then formula will return **4**.

Comment: It seems that the result is not correct. It should be 14, not 6.

Comment: @JOY, I've added a solution to count all occurences of a string. I hope it fits your need.

Comment: I don't want to count "Heroes" the same as "Hero". Instead, "hero", "HERO", "Hero" are count as the same.

Comment: There is one more issue: This doesn't count "afk" in "AFK-Spiel". I need it to be counted while "afk" in "afkxxx" is not. Is it possible?

Comment: @JOY, I've updated first formula to support that case

Comment: Sorry I meant I don't want to count hero in "heroes" or "heroic" but I want to count in "hero-666".

Answer (score 1):

In your sheet you mention that the count should be 14.
Considering that, I believe you are looking for a solution to also include words like `heroes` or `Hero`

If you want to include variations of `hero`, like `Hero` or `Heroes` you can use the following:

**Case insensitive for any language formula**:

```
=COUNTIF(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(B1:B3), " "), "*heRO*")
```

You can even have `*heRO*` placed in a cell like `A7` and use

```
=COUNTIF(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(B1:B3), " "), A7)
```

If you want just the word `Hero`, remove the asterisks `*` around it.

It also **works for any language** *(including German)*.

Comment: This works and is similar to @Tom approach. Thank you

Comment: *"...is similar to @Tom approach"* Appears very similar. Please try `=COUNTA(SPLIT(UPPER(JOIN(" ",C1:C3)), "für", false, false))-1` with `Für` or `xxxfür` in the text. In any case all right solutions may have variations. Most of the times there are more than just one approaches to an issue.

Comment: better use TEXTJOIN to replace CONCATENATE so that we can join them by a specific delimiter, otherwise if you have "heroherohero" ended up in one cell, they'll be counted only once

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IFERROR(SPLIT(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(
 UPPER(B1:B3), UPPER(A5), "♦"),,99^99), "♦")))-1)
```

and for german:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IFERROR(SPLIT(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(
 UPPER(C1:C3), "HELD", "♦"),,99^99), "♦")))-1)
```